# Developing .NET Applications on Windows 7 for XP/Vista

Tags: .net

Could somebody point me at some info or pros/cons for using Windows 7 as a development machine? I'm just curious if I develop an application using Visual Studio 2003/5/8 on Windows 7 am i going to run into any issues deploying it to earlier versions of windows... xp/vista/windows server etc.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see how you could possibly run into any issues. As long as the .NET framework versions are compatible (e.g. you don't develop using the 3.5 version on Windows 7 and deploy on an XP machine with the 2.0 version installed) it should be perfectly compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it myself, without any issues. Targetting users on Windows XP.

Just cant use the Windows 7 features of course!

Comment: .NET 3.5sp1 doesn't have anything Windows 7 specific anyway.  You need the Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework for that: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Answer (score 1):

as long as you write and use managed code everything will be alright

Comment: Do we need this on a t-shirt :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been developing on Windows 7 since January with Visual Studio 2008 and .Net 3.5 without issue. I have done mostly web applications using IIS7, but I have also done WPF development. In terms of previous versions, I see no reason why you would have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more related to .Net framwwork than the OS version. For example,you develop your application on Windows 7 targeting .Net framework 3.5, as long as you have .Net Framework 3.5 running in previous version of OS, it shouldn't cause problem.